# working directory in gnuplot

Tags: r, gnuplot, plotting

How do I specify the **working directory** for **gnuplot** in interactive mode?
If I want to call a script with `"call 'label_loop.gnu'"` and do not want to put the script file in the gnuplot installation folder, do I need to specify the full path each time? I think the following would be the case with normal usage. "I put the data or script I want to load in any directory"-> "I plot it in interactive mode"-> "I want to adjust the position of the label (preferably) with the mouse action"- > "I copy and paste the previous commands and I create a batch file"-> "GnuPlot converts the output to PDF"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clearly, look for `GNUPLOT_LIB` in `man gnuplot`:

> **GNUPLOT_LIB**
>
> Additional  search  directories for data and command files. The variable may contain a single directory name, or a list of
> directories separated by ':'. The contents of GNUPLOT_LIB are appended to the "loadpath" variable, but not saved with the "save" and
> "save
> set" commands.

So, just call `gnuplot` with the environment variable you want:

```
GNUPLOT_LIB=my/chosen/path gnuplot
```

For example, this plots a curve for the points (0,0), (1,1) and (2,3):

```
$ cat Test/data.dat
0 0
1 1
2 3
$ GNUPLOT_LIB=Test gnuplot 
gnuplot> plot 'data.dat' with lines
```